# C struct type confusing

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memcpy, payload

```
struct payload{
    struct metadata meta;
    char data_pointer[0];
};

struct payload* mypayload = (struct payload*) malloc(sizeof(struct payload) + 50);
```

What is the type of mypayload here?
The address, pointer, or something else

Comment: The type is exactly `struct payload *`. That is, a pointer to a struct.

Comment: It's a pointer (to struct payload). As all pointers, it contains an address in memory. The block of memory starting at this address should contain a struct payload.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` returns an untyped chunk of memory, and the assignment is how you tell the compiler what type it is.  In this case `struct payload *` which is a pointer (an address) of the memory that was allocated or NULL if the allocation failed.

You don't need the cast `(struct payload*)`.

If you want `data_pointer` to be a flexible array member, then you leave the size unspecified `char data_pointer[];`.  An array of size `0` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the type of `mypayload` here?

`mypayload` is a *pointer*, a pointer to a `struct payload`. [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985499/c-struct-type-confusing/71985701#comment127199056_71985499)

---

A `struct` array member with size 0, like `char data_pointer[0];` is not defined by C although some implementations had allowed it as a pre-cursor to  a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (FAM).

Since C99 use `char data_pointer[];` to define the *last* member as a *flexible array member*.

To best allocate for a *flexible array member*, compute the sum of 2 sizes:

- `sizeof mypayload[0]`: Size of the object up to, but not including the FAM member.  This will include any padding before the FAM member.
- `sizeof mypayload->data_pointer[0]`: Size of the FAM referenced data times the count, 50, of array elements desired.
- Tip: a *type* is not needed in the `sizeof` code.  Easier to code right, review and maintain to use the size of the referenced object.
- Tip: Cast not needed.
- Tip: Check for allocation success.

Example:

```
struct payload{
  struct metadata meta;
  char data_pointer[];  // No 0
};

struct payload* mypayload = malloc(
    sizeof mypayload[0] + 
    sizeof mypayload->data_pointer[0] * 50);
if (mypayload == NULL) {
  ; // TBD code to handle out-of-memory
}
```

Comment: How to use the data_pointer as a dynamic array instead of using the specific 50

Comment: @XiangfengLin Instead of `50`, use `n` like `size_t n = rand() % 100 + 1; struct payload* mypayload = malloc(sizeof mypayload[0] + sizeof mypayload.data_pointer[0] * n);`.  Note: `data_pointer` is not a _dynamic array_.  It is a pointer to a `struct` that has a dynamic array member.

Comment: @XiangfengLin [Comment correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985499/c-struct-type-confusing/71985701?noredirect=1#comment127199518_71985701) -- use `n` like `size_t n = rand() % 100 + 1; struct payload* mypayload = malloc(sizeof mypayload[0] + sizeof mypayload->data_pointer[0] * n);`.

Answer (score -1):

`mypayload` is a pointer. It's a pointer to the memory allocated by `malloc()`. And you have it configured as a pointer to a `payload`.